# Thread was being aborted issue while trying to download pdf file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

```
string bankcode = Session["BankCode"].ToString();
        string filename = bankcode.ToUpper() + "_Bank_Link_Form.pdf";
        try
        {
            string strURL = ResolveUrl("~/UI/doc/"+bankcode.ToLower()+".pdf");
            WebClient req = new WebClient();
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.Buffer = true;
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename="+filename);
            //byte[] data = req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(strURL));
            //req.DownloadFile(strURL, filename);
            //response.BinaryWrite(data);

           // Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=SailBig.jpg");
            Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(strURL));
            response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
```

this is the code i used for downloading pdf file. Though the file gets downloaded i getting an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Response.End()` in this case is used to prevent anything else from being added to the response as it may corrupt your file. The `Server.Transfer()`, `Response.End()`, `Response.Redirect()` all raise exceptions. Each of these methods internally call `Response.End()` and causes a `ThreadAbortException` exception.